# compare and report change in group membership in r tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

I get a list of group membership that is updated every day. I'd like to detect when group membership changes. I can do this if the group ID stays the same, but the wrinkle is that the group ID changes every day. Example below, I'd like to know that Fran was added to the group with Joe et al and that Arthur replaced Doug in Sam's group.
Any advice on how to get started with this?
Thanks

```
day1 <- 
  tibble(people = c("Joe", "Jane", "Max", "Sam", "Doug"), group = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2))

day2 <-
  tibble(people = c("Joe", "Jane", "Max", "Fran", "Sam", "Arthur"), group = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4))
```

Comment: Try `dplyr::full_join(day1,day2,by = 'people')`

Comment: Thanks @Duck this works well, should be able to flag all the changes I need. How can I mark yours as answer?

Comment: I will add as a solution now!

Comment: I have added as a solution as you suggested. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
df <- full_join(day1,day2,by = 'people')
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `merge` with `all = TRUE` from `base R`

```
df <- merge(day1, day2, by = "people", all = TRUE)
```